# How can I know whether ListItemId is a Folder or a Document in SharePoint Hosted App Using JSOM?

Tags: office-365, jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app

I created SharePoint Hosted App.
I Used Following Rest Call to Get File Name and Server Relative URL. But a problem is that when I get data in a result how can I know whether it is a Folder or a File and If it is a folder I need all Files List Inside a Folder.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
var listid = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPListId")).slice(1, -1);
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPHostUrl"));
var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPAppWebUrl"));
var itemIds = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPListItemId")).split(',');

function getListVersioningInfo(itemIdd) {

$.ajax({

    url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists('"+listid+"')/items(" + itemIdd + ")?$select=*&$expand=File",


    method: "GET",
    async: false,


    headers: {

        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"

    },

    success: function (data) {

        var fileName = data.d.File.Name;
        var filePath = data.d.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
        filePathArray.push(filePath);
        console.log(filePath);

       // alert("Success" + fileName);
    },

    error: function (data) {

        console.log(data)

    }

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using JSOM we can achieve it using this Rest Call:

```
url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists('" + listid + "')/items(" + itemIdd + ")?$select=*&$expand=File,ContentType,Folder",
```

so in result we get

```
var IsFolder=data.d.ContentType.Name
var FolderName=data.d.Folder.Name
```